# Generating random letters from string at odd indexes and even indexes

Tags: python, python-3.x

Two strings like:

```
import random
consonants = "bcdfghjklmnprstvwz"
vowels = "aeiou"
```

I want to get four letters at even indexes and three letters at odd indexes like:

```
ejiguka / agewilu / isavonu (odd indexes(0,2,4,6),even indexes(1,3,5,7))
```

I tried this function but it doesn't work.

```
random_letter = random.choice(consonants[::2])
random_letter1 = random.choice(vowels[1::2])
random_together = random_letter + random_letter1
```

I got two random letters like `b` and `e`, but I want to get output like `ejiguka` / `agewilu`.

Comment: What is the output of that code?

Comment: Please edit your Question with that information, don't just leave it in the comments.

Comment: @user8016886 You'll find `random.sample` a better alternative, it chooses unique elements. (look at my answer)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You're on the right track with splicing, but you're not applying it right.

First initialise an empty list:

```
In [134]: x = [None] * 7
```

Now, assign in splices, using `random.sample` to retrieve a unique random subset of characters:

```
In [135]: x[::2] = random.sample(vowels, 4)
     ...: x[1::2] = random.sample(consonants, 3)
```

Join and print:

```
In [136]: ''.join(x)
Out[136]: 'ijepula'
```

Comment: How to convert the output to a string?

Comment: @user8016886 Look at `''.join(x)`

Answer (score 0):

You could create a list of the letters and join them together like this:

```
str1 = ''.join(random.choice(consonants) if i % 2 else random.choice(vowels) for i in range(7))
```

Your code as it is is only getting one letter from each list, and only from the sliced items.

```
cons = (random.choice(consonants) for i in range(3))
vwls = (random.choice(vowels) for i in range(4))

''.join(next(cons) if i % 2 else next(vwls) for i in range(7))
```

Comment: There are lots of way you could split it into more lines. I added an edit that shows what's happening a little more clearly. Of course you could split into even more if you wanted.

Comment: I tired your code, I got repeat letters like :udurute, ebolafe.

Comment: They're random. There's only only 5 to choose form, so it's natural that some will show up more than once.